# What is the pronunciation of "liceity"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

"Liceity", meaning *lawfulness* or *legitimacy*, is a word that seems only to be used to describe certain religious actions from the Roman Catholic point of view. The word is not present in any major dictionaries, including the OED, but [this one](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34594) has it for example. What is its pronunciation?

If possible, please give sourced answers, but don't hesitate to speak from experience if you don't know of any sources but do know the answer.

Comment: Presumably it rhymes with *simultaneity* or *deity*.  With, or maybe with *nicety*, but that’s different.

Comment: Since it derives from *licentia*, I would guess *lic-* as in *licit* and *-eity* as with *deity*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m not convinced that it’s a valid word, because the *-eity* suffix denotes “a noun of quality or condition corresponding to adjectives in *-eous* suffix” [OED]. *Liceous* for *licit* is at best doubtful.

However, in the absence of authoritative data such as the OED might provide, it would be reasonable to assign a pronunciation based on other *-eity* words. In these (at least in British English) the *-e-* is stressed, the preceding syllable is unstressed and possibly reduced, and the pronunciation might therefore be presumed to be /liˈseɨti/.

Pronouncing an unusual word in a reasonably standard way may help the hearer to spell it and thereby to understand it: /liˈseɨti/ is likely to be spelled *liceity;* the *lic-* part is probably to do with *law* and the *-eity* part denotes a “noun of condition” and thus the word may be presumed to mean *lawfulness*.

Footnote: Documents of the Roman Catholic Church are always published in Latin first and then translated, so it’s entirely possible that a standard Latin word for *licitness* — such as *liceitatem* — has been clumsily translated as *liceity*.

Comment: Google Books reports Latin *liceitas, -atem* at least as far back as the 16th century, and Italian *liceitá* since the 17th. The earliest instance of *liceity* I find is in *The Irish Ecclesiastical Record* for June 1885. In all uses I have examined the Latin and English terms are employed in contrast with *validitas, validity*: that is, distinguishing the *lawfulness* of the performance of a (for example) a sacrament from its *effectiveness*.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, the [OP's link](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34594) contrasts validity with liceity. It's easy to see how it's derived from validitas/validity, liceitas/liceity. Anyway, the word's validity or lack of it doesn't affect the need to pronounce it.

Comment: I would guess that the first *i* would have the one in *sit* (and the first one in *licit*), so `/lɪˈseɨti/` — but it might be subject to reduction like the second one in *licit*, since it is unstressed.

Comment: I believe the pronunciation with /i/ is older for the ending "-eity," although you don't list it at all: //lɪˈsiɨti/.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pronouncing it like "liz-ze-ty" or "li-zi-ah-ty"
I compared it to nicety, but figured out that it has the -ei- so it might be pronounced one of these two ways.